# Javascript ASMX web service call - Handling Exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, asmx

I've got a web service that returns me an array of strings. I call this service from my javascript...

```
WebPortal.WebPortalServices.GetAllProperties(success, fail);
```

Now this works fine, I have my success and fail functions in my javascript. There seems to be a limit, either its the file size of the array or maybe the item count in the array, but either way when I get above 2500~ strings in the returned array the call fails. I.e my fail function is called.

How can I get the reason the service failed in my 'fail' function? I get no errors in my ASMX when I step through the service, it returns the Array of strings fine.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function fail(arg)

{

```
alert("error has occured: " + arg._message);
```

}

Comment: Cant believe it was that simple, i did try something similar. Thanks :)