# How to get error message when a webservice method throw exception.

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, error-handling

I use **WebServiceProxy.invoke** to call a webservice Method. I realized that one of the parameter is a function to handle error that coming when the method throw an exception.

I try method **get_message()** to get the error message. This work-well when I access it from localhost. But when I access the method from remote computer, the message is changed by a standard error: *"There was an error processing the request"*.

```
callws = function (args) {
    // call webservice to fill content panel
    Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke(_servicePath, _serviceMethod, false,
            { contextKey: args }, Function.createDelegate(this, onSubmitComplete),
              Function.createDelegate(this, onSubmitError), args);
    }

onSubmitComplete = function (result, userContext, methodName) {
    ...
}

onSubmitError = function (result, userContext, methodName) {
    // note: this result.get_message() contain exception message when
    // accessed from localhost, but contain "There was an error processing the request"
    // when accessed from remote computer
    alert(result.get_message());
}
```

Comment: What kind of web service are you hitting (WCF, ASMX)?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438339/javascript-asmx-web-service-call-handling-exceptions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201095/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-thrown-by-asmx-services

Comment: @AhmadFirdaus what library (if any) are you using on the client side?  If it were something standard like jQuery or ExtJS, your Ajax call should have a config option like `error` or `fail` that you can use to handle the returned response (with error code and response text).

Answer (score 3):

ASP.net runtime errors are not meant to be displayed to your customers in deployment environment, your server is correctly configured not to show [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in deployment, in case you want to debug the code, you can either set the `mode` flag of the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your `web.config` to `off`, or leave it to be `RemoteOnly` and debug the code right on the server!